# Confirm UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

When I am using the `UIGestureRecognizer`, for example, when the user swipes right, I want to have a `UIAlertView` asking if he really wants to commit the action of swiping right.

I have tried to do so, but with no success.

Comment: I think you can test with UIGestureRecognizerState. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Check with delegate http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this,

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeRight:)];
gesture1.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];
```

In Action method,

```
-(void)didSwipeLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Are you sure to commit with its action" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:CKString(@"NO") otherButtonTitles:CKString(@"YES"),nil];
    [Alert show];
    Alert.tag=222;
    Alert.delegate=self;
    [Alert release];
}
```

In AlertView Delegate

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(alertView.tag==222) {
        if(buttonIndex==1)
        {
            //// Yes condition
        } else {
           ///// No condition
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see. So you don't even bother with the UIGestureRecognizer properties. Based on the tag. How come it says 222 then 111?

Comment: But wait, I have this in my delegate: [priceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [nameArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [mainTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

Comment: How can I access indexPath from the delegate?

Comment: Yes, I am deleting row from TableView.

Comment: Why not? I am confirming the delete?

Comment: But I don't want the red "Delete" button.

Comment: Really? Let me do quick search.

Comment: accept this answer..  and post the question with tableview code... then i will give the answer... I cant post that answer here.. bcz I will make confusion for others...

Comment: Done, I posted the message.

Answer (score 2):

In the `UIGestureRecogniser` event method, create a `UIAlertView` with the appropriate title/message.

Set the delegate of the `UIAlertView` to `self`, and in `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` you can either perform the action or not based on what the user tapped.

Comment: See my problem is when detecting which button was pressed in the UIAlertView, how do I access the UIGestureRecognizer state property? Could you please post example code for this part?